# looping "for..do" on bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

How to do a `for do` loop in bash shell for executing some application?

I have this code below, i want to run usb-servo app, given the value of usb-servo from 190 to 225, i have tried to run the code, but the `for do` didn't gave any output, my servo didn't move.

```
#! /bin/sh
i=190

sleep 0.4
for (( i=190;i<=225;i++ ))
do
echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 $i
done

#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 195
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 200
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 205
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 210
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 215
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 220
#echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 225
```

Comment: please post only relevant code. what are your expected results?

Comment: Why are you echoing a password to sudo?  Put yourself in  `/etc/sudoers` instead.  That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks fine, but you can also try it using a range and see if that prints what you want:

```
for i in {190..225}; do
    echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 $i
done
```

If neither this nor your loop print the expected output, the problem is not with the loop.  Probably an issue in your `usb-servo` command.

Comment: i expect that the output is the movement of the servo with the i value, i've tried with in range, but it gave me the movement of the servo to 0.

Comment: What is the exact output when you run the command outside the loop with a hard-coded value instead of $i?

Comment: When i run outside the loop, the output is status of the servo rotor position, if i change i to value 190, then that is the exact value of the servo rotor position.

Comment: So, "190" does get printed to the screen when you run `echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 190`, yes?

Comment: Yes it does get printed to the screen.

Comment: Then the only problem could be with the usb-servo command.  Verify that it does allow input values higher then 190 and that there are no typos in the command inside the loop.  Also try it with just `echo $i` inside the loop to confirm that the loop works as expected.

Comment: Solved like this: `for i in 190 200 210 220 225; do echo my_pass | sudo -S /usr/bin/usb-servo set 0 $i
sleep 0.01
#echo $i
done`